# Degree-$p$ étale covers of affine line

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, irreducible-polynomials, algebraic-curves, positive-characteristic

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of positive characteristic $p$. Suppose that $F$ is a monic irreducible polynomial over $k[x]$ of degree $p$ whose discriminant is an element of $k$. Is then $F$ necessarily of the form
$$F=T^p+aT+f(x),$$
for some $a\in k$ and $f(x)\in k[x]$?

I'm interested in this because I'm looking at degree-$p$ étale covers of the affine line $\mathbb{A}^1_k$. Of course Artin-Schreier covers like the above provide examples, and I know that there are non-Galois degree-$p$ étale covers of $\mathbb{A}_k^1$ as well. But are there any non-Artin-Schreier covers given by a polynomial $F$ as above with constant discriminant? If I am not mistaken, this means that the covering curve is a smooth plane curve.

Comment: Are you aware of https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0A3J?

Comment: Thanks for the link! I know that the Artin-Schreier sequence is exact in the étale topology, surjectivity essentially corresponding to the existence of Artin-Schreier covers as above... but I don't know how to rule out the existence of any other étale covers of degree $p$ given by a polynomial with discriminant a constant

Comment: You're also requiring that $F$ has degree $p$, correct? (I ask because I don't have the algebraic geometry background necessary to understand what a degree-$p$ étale cover is.)

Comment: @BenjaminWright Yes, thank you! I added this to the post (though I think the only additional case is that of $F$ having degree $1$)